# Android Programing with OpenCV - App is crashing

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv, image-processing, crash

I'm still new to Android programming and OpenCV.
I took one of the OpenCV examples which come along with the package (Tutorial 2 - Mixed Processing) and tried to modify some of the image transformations but although my changes were minimal, after I compile and install the altered sample on my Galaxy Note (4.1.2) the program wont run. As soon as I open the App the screen goes black and after a few moments I get the message that the App has stopped.

Note that when I compile and install the unaltered sample, the App runs without any problems.

I uploaded the complete package to my site
http://cheaib.de/Tutorial2Activity.rar

Here is the code

```
package org.opencv.samples.tutorial2;

import org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame;
import org.opencv.android.LoaderCallbackInterface;
import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class Tutorial2Activity extends Activity implements CvCameraViewListener2 {
private static final String    TAG = "OCVSample::Activity";

private static final int       VIEW_MODE_THRES1     = 0;
private static final int       VIEW_MODE_GRAY     = 1;
private static final int       VIEW_MODE_CANNY    = 2;
private static final int       VIEW_MODE_CANNY2 = 5;

private int                    mViewMode;
private Mat                    mRgba;
private Mat                    mIntermediateMat;
private Mat                    mGray;
private Mat                    mTemp1;

private MenuItem               mItemPreviewThres1;
private MenuItem               mItemPreviewGray;
private MenuItem               mItemPreviewCanny;
private MenuItem               mItemPreviewCanny2;

private CameraBridgeViewBase   mOpenCvCameraView;

private BaseLoaderCallback  mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        switch (status) {
            case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
            {
                Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");

                // Load native library after(!) OpenCV initialization
                System.loadLibrary("mixed_sample");

                mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
            } break;
            default:
            {
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
            } break;
        }
    }
};

public Tutorial2Activity() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Instantiated new " + this.getClass());
}

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i(TAG, "called onCreate");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    setContentView(R.layout.tutorial2_surface_view);

    mOpenCvCameraView = (CameraBridgeViewBase) findViewById    (R.id.tutorial2_activity_surface_view);
    mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    Log.i(TAG, "called onCreateOptionsMenu");
    mItemPreviewThres1 = menu.add("Preview Thres1");
    mItemPreviewGray = menu.add("Preview Gray");
    mItemPreviewCanny = menu.add("Preview Canny");
    mItemPreviewCanny2 = menu.add("Preview Canny2");
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
        mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_3, this, mLoaderCallback);
}

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
        mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
}

public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
    mRgba = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC4);
    mIntermediateMat = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC4);
    mGray = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC1);
    mTemp1 = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC1);
}

public void onCameraViewStopped() {
    mRgba.release();
    mGray.release();
    mIntermediateMat.release();
    mTemp1.release();
}

public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    final int viewMode = mViewMode;
    switch (viewMode) {
    case VIEW_MODE_GRAY:
        // input frame has gray scale format
        Imgproc.cvtColor(inputFrame.gray(), mRgba, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGBA, 4);
        break;
    case VIEW_MODE_THRES1:
        // input frame has gray scale format
        Imgproc.threshold(inputFrame.gray(), mTemp1, 150, 255, 0);
        Imgproc.cvtColor(mTemp1, mRgba, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGBA, 4);
        break;
    case VIEW_MODE_CANNY:
        // input frame has gray scale format
        mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
        Imgproc.Canny(inputFrame.gray(), mIntermediateMat, 80, 100);
        Imgproc.cvtColor(mIntermediateMat, mRgba, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGBA, 4);
        break;
    case VIEW_MODE_CANNY2:
        // input frame has gray scale format
        Imgproc.threshold(inputFrame.gray(), mTemp1, 150, 255, 0);
        mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
        Imgproc.Canny(mTemp1, mIntermediateMat, 80, 100);
        Imgproc.cvtColor(mTemp1, mRgba, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGBA, 4);
        break;
    }

    return mRgba;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Log.i(TAG, "called onOptionsItemSelected; selected item: " + item);

    if (item == mItemPreviewThres1) {
        mViewMode = VIEW_MODE_THRES1;
    } else if (item == mItemPreviewGray) {
        mViewMode = VIEW_MODE_GRAY;
    } else if (item == mItemPreviewCanny) {
        mViewMode = VIEW_MODE_CANNY;
    } else if (item == mItemPreviewCanny2) {
        mViewMode = VIEW_MODE_CANNY2;
    }

    return true;
}

//public native void FindFeatures(long matAddrGr, long matAddrRgba);
}
```

I hope you can help me to find out why the app is crashing.
Eclipse is not giving me any error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you compiled the C++ files using NDK? Mixed Processing and Face detection require the C++ files in JNI to be compiled first.